# Switched to GNOME, no password prompt on wakeup

Tags: unity, gnome, suspend, password, settings

After months of using Ubuntu I decided to switch from Unity to GNOME. Everything is working fine except it seems like some settings haven't carried over. When I close my laptop and reopen it, it doesn't prompt for a password even though I have it set to do so. Are the GNOME settings stored separately, so I have to change them manually?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

gnome-screensaver wasn't added to the startup applications, so I added it to that and all is well.